# What happens if you don't kill Crispin?

Tags: watch-dogs

I just completed the mission where you have to kill Crispin in order to

> assume his identity for the auction.

Near the end of the mission, Clara says something along the lines of

> "Maybe we had to kill Crispin, but at least we can save the girl" (Poppy)

I retried the mission many times attempting to beat it without killing Crispin, but I can't get close enough to him before he runs away.

So, is it possible to knock out Crispin, rather than killing him?  Does it affect the storyline or the dialog at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I managed to knock out Crispin without killing him by using a Blackout and running past his guards.

Unfortunately, the dialog was exactly the same *(Clara still says "Maybe we had to kill Crispin...")*, so most likely the storyline is not affected at all. Oh well.

Comment: There's a few places like this where the dialog does not line up with the events, depending on how you played. E.g. stealthing into the first ctOS server ("I made a lot of noise here"), or knocking out everyone when you are rescuing your nephew ("He saw me kill all those people").

Answer (score 1):

You can't not kill Crispin, even if you knock him out it counts as him being killed (I played full stealth without shooting unless I really had to).
What Clara meant is maybe something good (saving the girl) can come out of this, even though you had to do something bad initially (killing Crispin)

Comment: *"You can't not kill Crispin, even if you knock him out it counts as him being killed"* - That's not true.  When you kill him and highlight his body, it says *"Dead,"* but when you knock him out it says *"Knocked out."*

Comment: It counts as killed story wise.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hack the phone rather then killing him crispin from the wall behind tthe car dealers but dialogue was same